# Can a piecewise function be called decreasing or increasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I define a function
$f(x)= \frac{(x-1)}{(x-2)} $
where x is not equal to 2.

Can we say that the function is "decreasing for all values of x" seeing that the left hand limit at 2 is negative infinity while the right hand limit is positive infinity?

I can see that the function decreases piecewise in each interval of its domain i. e. It decreases in $(1, 2) $ and $(2, \infty) $ but the function does increases when we go from a value just less than 2 to one just more than 2, so is the function "decreasing for all values of x" here?

Comment: Typically decreasing is defined to mean $x\gt y\implies f(x)\lt f(y)$ which is not the case here as you say.